# Stacked justGage gauges with offset text

Tags: html, css, justgage

I have a temp and humidity sensor run by a Raspberry Pi in my server room posting data to a MySQL database. I can pull the temp and humidity data from the database and graph each one separately without problem, as shown below.
[image: Separate temp and humidity readings]

Id like to stack the gauges so the temperature is under the humidity reading (hence the fatter bar). The divs stack okay, but the text is overlayed, as expected. Is it possible to make the value follow the pointer, or at least push the readings to the left and right sides so they don't overlap?

[image: Overlapped gauges]

I have textRenderer properties showing low and high out-of-bounds conditions, as well as a color changing graph. The extra text would definitely overlap in the condition shown. What I'd like is to be able to position the temperature text outside of the gauges and position the humidity text inside the gauges, both following the pointer. Is this possible?

[image: textRenderer properties.]

Comment: if you show us your HTML code we will be able to help you better. It sounds like its CSS related and where your divs are positioned or you used the same div name to place the gage.